# laravel 5 composer update omnipay fails

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, omnipay

I am having a problem with composer when I run `composer update`.

The relevant bits of my `composer.json` file looks like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "omnipay/common": "~2.0",
    "omnipay/authorizenet": "~2.0",
    "omnipay/firstdata": "~2.0",
    "omnipay/stripe": "~2.0",
    "omnipay/paypal": "~2.0"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

When I run `composer update`, I receive the following error:

```
[Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]
Problem 1
  - The requested package omnipay/common could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 2
  - Installation request for omnipay/authorizenet ~2.0 -> satisfiable by omnipay/authorizenet[2.5.0].
  - omnipay/authorizenet 2.5.0 requires omnipay/common ~2.2 -> no matching package found.
Problem 3
  - Installation request for omnipay/firstdata ~2.0 -> satisfiable by omnipay/firstdata[v2.3.0].
  - omnipay/firstdata v2.3.0 requires omnipay/common ~2.0 -> no matching package found.
Problem 4
  - Installation request for omnipay/stripe ~2.0 -> satisfiable by omnipay/stripe[v2.4.3].
  - omnipay/stripe v2.4.3 requires omnipay/common ~2.0 -> no matching package found.
Problem 5
  - Installation request for omnipay/paypal ~2.0 -> satisfiable by omnipay/paypal[v2.6.3].
  - omnipay/paypal v2.6.3 requires omnipay/common ~2.0 -> no matching package found.  
Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
 see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.  Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I'm at a loss as to what direction to take to fix this or why it occurred in the first place.  I last ran composer update several months ago and it ran with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to specifically require omnipay/common or omnipay/omnipay (which is a dummy package anyway).

(1) remove all of the omnipay/* lines from your composer.json

(2) The composer commands you need to bring your composer.json into having the correct versions are:

```
composer require omnipay/authorizenet
composer require omnipay/firstdata
composer require omnipay/stripe
composer require omnipay/paypal
```

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.  Did not know I just needed to re-require the packages. I just had the require omnipay/omnipay as a troubleshooting step.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command, I think composer will update your dependencies.

```
composer require omnipay/omnipay
```

I suppose the problem is with the package name. You can add omnipay/omnipay in your composer.json file as the package name.

Answer (score 0):

I hope You Read  All The Error Once. Its All Package You Declare is not found or not getting or  its required update So, Just Remove the All The `omipay packge` form the `Coposer.json` and also Remove from  `ServiceProvider`  in `config/app.php`

**Example** Remove This Code Form **Composer.json**

```
"omnipay/common": "~2.0",
"omnipay/authorizenet": "~2.0",
"omnipay/firstdata": "~2.0",
"omnipay/stripe": "~2.0",
"omnipay/paypal": "~2.0"
```

And Then Try To Update Your `Composer` and Then After Install New Version Package From  [Here](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal)

I Hope Its Work For Your !!

**Or**

> Follow This :

**And Install The Package Again From  :**

https://packagist.org/packages/omnipay/paypal

**And**

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal